# How to the closed opportunity and closed by whom using soql query in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, soql

How to get, closed opportunity and who closed the opportunity in salesforce using SOQL query?  I am getting the closed opportunity using [SELECT Id , Name FROM OpportunityStage WHERE  IsClosed = true] soql query,but i am not sure how to find who closed the opportunity?

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not compile, there's no `Name` field in [`OpportunityStage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitystage.htm) table. That table hosts only config data about stages, not tied to any particular opportunity. You're completely off the mark.

You could query [`OpportunityHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm) (for just stage-related changes) or [`OpportunityFieldHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm) for the normal field history tracking stuff (your admin chose which fields are worth tracking)

This might be a good start, you'll have to experiment to fit your needs

```
SELECT OpportunityId, Opportunity.Name, StageName, Probability, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
FROM OpportunityHistory
WHERE Probability IN (0, 100)
```

If you know nobody edits closed opportunities then you don't even need history tables,

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedBy.Name
FROM Opportunity
WHERE IsClosed = true
```

would be enough. Or maybe you could write to some helper field the name / id of user that closed the opp (flow, workflow, process builder, trigger...)